"The most important thing is / are..."
Question. Which is grammatically correct:

The most important thing are people.

The most important thing is people.


My dilemma is with using either "is" or "are."
I am incline to use "is" since we are talking about "thing" (singular).
But for some reason, I feel discombobulated when I say something like:

The most important thing is cars.


The correct one should be:

The most important thing is people.

When you are mentioning “most important thing” (subject), we use “is” (verb). Otherwise, for “most important things” (subject), it should be “are” (verb). The verb always follows the subject.
The same thing goes to:

The most important thing is cars.

"cars" in this case becomes a composite singular, referring to a single group of cars.
